# Selenium function returns empty list using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I've written this function in C# using Selenium. I first locate the specification tab, then I locate the "spec_line" classes, and then want to locate the title and description in it. I see while debugging that it has found six elements to loop over (which is correct), in the title and description are always filled with elements too. When I want the text out of it using ".Text" is seems to be empty however.

Can someone see the problem why it hasn't any values? second question is how can you debug this, for now if I saw an an element in the variable and got the text out of it it always worked, now I'm stuck.

URL I want to scrape: https://www.moss-europe.co.uk/gaiter-gear-lever-rubber-bhh2049.html

function

```
public List<string[]> GetModel(IWebDriver driver)
{
    IWebElement parentElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.wrapper > div > div.page-border > div.main.col1-layout > div.col-main > div.product-view > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul"));
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lines = parentElement.FindElements(By.ClassName("spec_line"));

    List<string[]> modelDetails = new List<string[]>();
    foreach (IWebElement line in lines)
    {
        IWebElement title = line.FindElement(By.ClassName("spec_title"));
        IWebElement description = line.FindElement(By.ClassName("spec_desc"));

        string[] detail = { title.Text, description.Text };
        modelDetails.Add(detail);
    }
    return modelDetails;
}
```

I tried to debug it and saw that all the variables are filled with elements, I know for sure that there's text in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click first on specification tab in order these elements to be visible

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'specification']")).Click();
```

For a more robust solution you could use the `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` nuget package, this will give you access to a bunch of helper expected conditions methods.

For the same scenario using some waiting methods:

```
// The model you need to store the values
record Model(string Title, string Description)
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Title}: {Description}";
    }
}
```

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

const string Url = @"https://www.moss-europe.co.uk/gaiter-gear-lever-rubber-bhh2049.html";

using var driver = new ChromeDriver();

// Setup your `wait`
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
{ 
    PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)
};

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);

// Wait for the tab to be visible and then click
wait
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'specification']")))
    .Click();

var models = new List<Model>();

// Wait for all lines with elements to be visible
var lines = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.ClassName("spec_line")));
foreach (var line in lines)
{    
    var title = line.FindElement(By.ClassName("spec_title")).Text;
    var description = line.FindElement(By.ClassName("spec_desc")).Text;

    models.Add(new Model(title, description));
}

// Just to demo the results
foreach (var mod in models)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mod);
}
```